# Why don't new Stack Overflow questions get as many views as like 4 years ago?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions, views

I was out of the coding game for a while. Now I noticed, without considering the question time, that it's really rare for a question to get at least 1/4 of the views that a question asked a couple of years ago would get.

What's been changed since then?

Comment: FYI the correct spelling is Stack Overflow, with a space. See the last paragraph [here](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Three possible causes:

- Old questions have been gaining views for a far longer period of time than newer questions.
  For a fair comparison, you need to compare the number of views questions get in their first week (or month).
- The technology where your questions pertain to has decreased in popularity; if there are fewer fellow developers in technology X, they will be less likely to find your question and increase the # of views.
- The total number of questions rises more rapidly than the total number of views. There are certainly more questions than 4 years ago; whether the total number of views has seen the same growth, we can probably derive from the analytics tools or SEDE.

Comment: Right. I have several Visual Basic posts that get almost no attention nowadays because - who uses VB anymore? I'm not deleting them - they are there for those brave souls who yearn for the elder days tech of our ancestors and quest for ye olde solutions of yore.

Comment: good for you, you are loved, Im hated :))